# Create Word document from Excel database

Tags: excel, ms-word, excel-2003

I have an Excel sheet with `username`, `password` and `e-mail` columns and I want to generate a Word document - every page would contain one row from the Excel sheet, so I can print this document and distribute to every user their own page.

I did the same thing 5 or 6 years ago (without any VB code) so I know it is possible.

I'm using Office 2003.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't call Excel a `database`. ;)  Nevertheless this is very well possible.

Word has a [*mail merge*](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/word-mail-merge-a-walk-through-the-process-HA001034920.aspx) feature. It allows you to take one source document and fill in some fields. Then merge it with a data source, like an Excel sheet, to get a resulting document that repeats the source document for each row in the sheet.

I'm pretty sure you must have used this feature, back then.

I'm using Word 2010, which has a separate ribbon dedicated to Mail Merge, and the wizards is docked to the side. I don't recall exactly in which menu mail merge could be found in Word 2003, but it should be fairly easy to find it now you know the name of the feature.

{edit} I see now that the [tutorial](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/word-mail-merge-a-walk-through-the-process-HA001034920.aspx) I linked to, applies to Word 2003. :D